# Replace the jQuery function with my own

Tags: jquery, function, overriding

Here I'm required to use `id.text = value` instead of `$('#id').val('value')` as in jQuery.

How can I use my own syntax format to do this?

Comment: sorry... what do you mean...

Comment: JQuery is built on top of Javascript. You can revert to native Javascript at any time, and it'll keep running just fine - there's nothing special you have to do, to make that work. Unfortunately it means you have to learn enough Javascript to handle all the browser-specific quirks that JQuery normally smooths over.

Comment: You are trying to change the basic selector of jquery and for that you need to write seperate library bcoz jquery will not allow you to change their syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain Javascript replacement for the jQuery statement:

```
$('#someid').val('some value');
```

is this:

```
document.getElementById("someid").value = 'some value';
```

---

There is no jQuery or regular DOM syntax that lets you do: `id.text = 'some value';` that will assign the `.value` property of a DOM element.

You could define your own jQuery replacement object and give it a `.text` property with a getter and setter and then you could make a syntax like that work.  It would have nothing to do with jQuery at that point since you'd be creating your own object type and would have to initialize it with some sort of DOM reference inside so it knew what DOM element it was connected to.

But, you haven't really explained why you would reinvent what either the DOM API or jQuery has already defined so it's hard to know what exactly you're trying to accomplish above and beyond what is already there for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just use vanilla js.

`document.getElementById('yourid')`

Comment: is this a real answer?, the question is not even clear, but i guess you understood it